# What is simplest Python code to call the begin_time function with the value of time equal to 5 when the launch Button is pressed?

Tags: gpio, python, gpiozero

I have the following code:

```
def begin_time(time):
    print(time)

from gpiozero import Button

begin = Button(27)
```

I want to call this function with time = 5

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on what you want the program to do while waiting for the button to be pressed.  [Button abilities here](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html)

You could try (untested code though):

```
from gpiozero import Button
import time

def begin_time(time):
    print(time)


begin = Button(27)

# Loop doing nothing till the button is pressed        
while being.is_held == False:
   time.sleep(0.01)

# Button pressed so call function
begin_time(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that takes no parameters:

```
def begin_time_5():
    begin_time(5)

begin.when_pressed = begin_time_5
```

This is called "currying".

Alternatively, use a lambda:

```
begin.when_pressed = lambda: begin_time(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if it’s tight you want:

```
def begin_time(time = 5):
    print(time)

begin.when_pressed = begin_time
```

Personally, I find this easier to understand than the more pythonic lambda :-) but have to say the lambda version has more flexibility for changing the value.